# Git one-liner to add everything (including untracked files) and commit

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit, git-add

I'm really lazy, so I often like to run `git commit -am 'msg'` to add and commit everything in one swoop. If I'm lucky, I haven't added any untracked files and this will work fine. However, sometimes I'll do this, run `git status` much later in the midst of some other work, realize I messed up, and then have to do acrobatics with `git stash` and `git reset` to put the untracked files in the proper commit. This is really time-consuming.

I'm wondering if there's a way to both stage changes *and* add untracked files and commit with a single git command. Something that would be the equivalent of

```
git add -A :/
git commit -m 'msg'
```

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 0):

You can add commit the one file or multiple files:

```
git add /file1 /folder/file2 ...
git commit -m "message"

// single file
git add /file3
git commit -m "message"
```